# TypeError: callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

Tags: python, tkinter

I get this error every time I click a button using Tkinter. I'm not quite sure what it means that 0 arguments are given, because I thought that callback gives two arguments. Traceback of the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in call return self.func(*args)   
TypeError: callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Here is all my code related to callback

```
def callback(input_set, user_set):
    user_score = 0
    if len(input_set & user_set) == 0:
        user_score += len(input_set - user_set) * 2
    for multiplier, user_set in enumerate(user_sets, 1):
        user_score += len(input_set & user_set) * multiplier

    print "Congratulations, you've scored " + str(user_score) + " points!"

# Creates button to calculate score
self.button = Tkinter.Button(self, font="Arial", text="Click to get your score", 
                             width = 45, pady = 5, command = callback)
self.button.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="", columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Do you think the next line up in the traceback would be helpful?

Comment: I didn't even notice it. Here it is:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

Comment: So `args` is empty. You need to trace back to see where it comes from

Comment: I do not have args anywhere in my code

Comment: I edited it into my question at the end

Comment: First, can't help you with tkinter, do not use it and know nothing about callback args. But from your definition no place where they are defined exists, so you should consult docs about passing args to callbacks. Second, your callback returns none (as print returns None), is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command = callback`

here you have to give the args that you are passing to callback. Use `command=lambda:callback(arg1,arg2)`

where arg1 & arg2 are the arguments that you need to provide the called function

Answer (score 2):

In your given function   `def callback(input_set, user_set):` , It takes two argument, I think when you click button using Tkinter, the two arguments are not passed into the callback function. you have to check that which arguments are passed into the function.

Comment: how do i check that? Sorry, I'm a beginner!

Comment: simple, debug your code. use  import pdb pdb.set_trace(), just above the code from where this function is called and then use terminal to see the arguments.

Comment: how do i use terminal?

Comment: `command = callback`. Here you have to give the args that you are passing to `callback`. Use `command=lambda:callback(arg1,arg2)` where `arg1` & `arg2` are the arguments that you need to provide the called function

Comment: @Alok Chaudhary you could add your comment as answer.